# Completely remove nm-applet from gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, 12.10, network-manager

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome Remix 12.10.
I have uninstalled `network-manager`, `network-manager-gnome`, etc... but in gnome-shell top bar panel remains the applet without icon:
[image: screenshot]

How can I completely remove nm-applet from gnome-shell?

Answer (score 1):

The *problem* was [icon hider extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/).